# Open smart home system with focus on alerting

Tags: home-automation

I am looking for a smart home solution with the focus on integrating various security sensors (water/flood sensors, gas sensor, carbon monoxide sensor, smoke sensor, maybe door/window sensors). The system should send alerts to one or more mobile phones.

I am looking for an open (source) solution, being able to integrate various vendors and/or technologies. I found Z-Wave and Zigbee to look promising. I have taken a look at Home Assistant, OpenHAB, FHEM and Z-Way - but there is little to no documentation on alerting capabilities, apps for mobile phones etc.

I'd prefer Linux since that would run on the Raspberry Pi's I already have here - but if it ends up with Windows, it would be OK.

Can someone give me a hint what would fit this use case? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using FHEM here on a Pi. Alerts should be possible (though I use none and never have played with that). At least email alerts should be no big issue to set up – so if you have a mail app on your mobile (which OS there?) you'd get your notification. There are also several companion apps supporting FHEM (unfortunately my server is currently down due to hardware issues, so it doesn't help much giving you a link to my corresponding app list; [andFHEM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=li.klass.fhem) would be one candidate).